# How to create Ticks Marks And Equal Spacing on a Radial Gauge?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I am a Software Developer and working on creating a front End dashboard. I am supposed to create all this without using any plugins. Just pure JQuery and JavaScript and styling. I am developing a radial Gauge from scratch without plugins. I need to add the following to my gauge. Please help me with it.

1. Tick Marks showing Min Value and Max Value from 0 to 100.

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}

#radial:before {
  background: yellowgreen;
  border-radius: 220px 220px 0 0;
  /* box-shadow: 3px 1px 8px rgba(2, 1, 1, 0.15) inset; */
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  
}

#radial {
  border-radius: 400px 400px 0 0;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  
}

#radial:after {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 140px 140px 0 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 3px 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  /* color: rgba(255, 80, 0, 0.7); */
  content: "";
  font-family: Lato, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  height: 70px;
  left: 30px;
  line-height: 95px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 140px;
  
}

#needle {
  background: radial-gradient(black, red);
  border-radius: 8px;
  bottom: -4px;
  /* box-shadow: 3px -1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); */
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  transform-origin: 100% 4px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition:8s ;
  z-index: 2;
  /* border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px; */
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0% 50%, 100% 100% );
  
}

#radial:hover span {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

/* h1,
p,
strong {
  display: block;
  font-family: Lato;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

strong {
  color: #be1e1e;
  font-size: 2.5em;
} */
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <tite></tite>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="GaugeCss_last.css">
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript"></script> -->
    </head>

    <head>
        
    </head>

    <body>
            <div id="radial" data-value="0">
            <span id="needle" value="8"></span>
            <span id="spacing"></span>
            </div>
        
        
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to modify your [current needle as a tick?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eThas.png)